# How to resolve a hung up msdt.exe (Microsoft Windows Update Troubleshooter)?

Tags: windows-8, windows-update

I am having an issue where Windows 8 will not apply updates and says an error occurred when installing an update.  To resolve it it recommended running the troubleshooter tool, which it then does. msdt.exe runs, and says "Resolving Problems", and a progress bar with no real progress indicator just the green "segment" that moves from left to right, appears.   20 hours later it is still not doing anything.  Rebooting, and trying again leads to the same result.